# sudo apt-get install libao-common

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libao-common
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 52 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/11.3 kB of archives.
After this operation, 49.2 kB of additional disk space will be used.
dpkg: regarding .../libao-common_1.1.0-2_armhf.deb containing libao-common:
 libao-common conflicts with libao2
  libao2 (version 0.8.4-1) is present and unpacked but not configured.

dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libao-common_1.1.0-2_armhf.deb (--unpack):
 conflicting packages - not installing libao-common
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libao-common_1.1.0-2_armhf.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Why is conflicting packages not installing `libao-common`?

It’s on a Raspberry PI with [Raspbian](http://www.raspbian.org/).

apt-get -f install doesn't work

```
root@raspberrypi:~# apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libao-common
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libao-common
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 52 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 11.3 kB of archives.
After this operation, 49.2 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Get:1 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy/main libao-common armhf 1.1.0-2 [11.3 kB]
Fetched 11.3 kB in 2s (4,117 B/s) 
dpkg: regarding .../libao-common_1.1.0-2_armhf.deb containing libao-common:
 libao-common conflicts with libao2
  libao2 (version 0.8.4-1) is present and unpacked but not configured.

dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libao-common_1.1.0-2_armhf.deb (--unpack):
 conflicting packages - not installing libao-common
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libao-common_1.1.0-2_armhf.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Try configuring the liba02 package again. It's there but it is not configured. You can sudo-apt-get install liba02 again (as a shortcut instead of configuring) and then try installing your liba0-common package again. Hope this helps.

Comment: `sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get autoremove` and try again.

Comment: @Sam it doesn't work! 
dpkg: regarding .../libao-common_1.1.0-2_armhf.deb containing libao-common:
 libao-common conflicts with libao2
  libao2 (version 0.8.4-1) is present and unpacked but not configured.

dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libao-common_1.1.0-2_armhf.deb (--unpack):
 conflicting packages - not installing libao-common
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libao-common_1.1.0-2_armhf.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: maybe you have installed yet an another version of libao?

Answer (score 1):

notice that message:

> 4 not fully installed or removed.

maybe you install other package failed. then the apt tool try to install them again.

so, uninstall these error package first.

```
sudo apt-get --force-yes remove #your-package-name#
```

you need to remove the 4 not fully installed or removed package first.

then

```
sudo apt autoremove
```

now, try to install the new package again.